# angular need to reload page for fb share button to show up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

I am trying to get facebooks share plugin up and running. The problem i have been running into is that I have to reload the page to actually get the share button to show up. If i navigate to the page through link or url the facebook share button will not show up, i have to reload the page and then the button will show up. I am using angular so thought to use a directive but so far my efforts have not been successful.

here is where I have the directive in my template

```
<div class="fb-share-button" fb-share data-href="{{fbUrl}}" data-layout="button" id='fb-share'></div>
```

here is my directive.

```
angular.module('App').directive('fbShare', function () {
    function createHTML(href, layout) {
        return '<div class="fb-share-button" ' +
                       'data-href="' + href + '" ' +
                       'data-layout="' + layout + '" ' +
               '</div>';
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('dataHref', function (newValue) {
                var href        = newValue;
                var layout    = attrs.layout    || 'button';

                elem.html(createHTML(href, layout));
                FB.XFBML.parse(elem[0]);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

the facebook sdk code which is just after the opening body tag

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=xxxxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
```

Comment: What's with the weird HTML creation? Just use a template

Comment: Have you added a `console.log` inside your `$observe` callback? Can you provide a plunkr.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a great set of directives for Angular sharing widgets including FB: http://plnkr.co/edit/OvZRK6?p=preview

Just set your FB APP ID and user a scope variable for your url, imageURl and Name.

If you view his code you can see how to render the code and possibly customize the FB template to your needs.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['angulike'])
  .run([
    '$rootScope',
    function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.facebookAppId = '85024842290'; // set your facebook app id here
    }
  ]);

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('myController', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.myModel = {
        Url: 'http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/08/01/AngularJS-directives-for-social-sharing-buttons-Facebook-Like-GooglePlus-Twitter-and-Pinterest.aspx',
        Name: "AngularJS directives for social sharing buttons - Facebook, Google+, Twitter and Pinterest | Jason Watmore's Blog",
        ImageUrl: 'http://www.jasonwatmore.com/pics/jason.jpg'
      };
    }
  ]);


/**
 * AngularJS directives for social sharing buttons - Facebook Like, Google+, Twitter and Pinterest
 * @author Jason Watmore <jason@pointblankdevelopment.com.au> (http://jasonwatmore.com)
 * @version 1.2.0
 */
(function() {
  angular.module('angulike', [])

  .directive('fbLike', [
    '$window', '$rootScope',
    function($window, $rootScope) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          fbLike: '=?'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          if (!$window.FB) {
            // Load Facebook SDK if not already loaded
            $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function() {
              $window.FB.init({
                appId: '85024842290',
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v2.0'
              });
              renderLikeButton();
            });
          } else {
            renderLikeButton();
          }

          var watchAdded = false;

          function renderLikeButton() {
            if (!!attrs.fbLike && !scope.fbLike && !watchAdded) {
              // wait for data if it hasn't loaded yet
              watchAdded = true;
              var unbindWatch = scope.$watch('fbLike', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                  renderLikeButton();

                  // only need to run once
                  unbindWatch();
                }

              });
              return;
            } else {
              element.html('<div class="fb-like"' + (!!scope.fbLike ? ' data-href="' + scope.fbLike + '"' : '') + ' data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>');
              $window.FB.XFBML.parse(element.parent()[0]);
            }
          }
        }
      };
    }
  ])

  .directive('googlePlus', [
    '$window',
    function($window) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          googlePlus: '=?'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          if (!$window.gapi) {
            // Load Google SDK if not already loaded
            $.getScript('//apis.google.com/js/platform.js', function() {
              renderPlusButton();
            });
          } else {
            renderPlusButton();
          }

          var watchAdded = false;

          function renderPlusButton() {
            if (!!attrs.googlePlus && !scope.googlePlus && !watchAdded) {
              // wait for data if it hasn't loaded yet
              watchAdded = true;
              var unbindWatch = scope.$watch('googlePlus', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                  renderPlusButton();

                  // only need to run once
                  unbindWatch();
                }

              });
              return;
            } else {
              element.html('<div class="g-plusone"' + (!!scope.googlePlus ? ' data-href="' + scope.googlePlus + '"' : '') + ' data-size="medium"></div>');
              $window.gapi.plusone.go(element.parent()[0]);
            }
          }
        }
      };
    }
  ])

  .directive('tweet', [
    '$window', '$location',
    function($window, $location) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          tweet: '=',
          tweetUrl: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          if (!$window.twttr) {
            // Load Twitter SDK if not already loaded
            $.getScript('//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', function() {
              renderTweetButton();
            });
          } else {
            renderTweetButton();
          }

          var watchAdded = false;

          function renderTweetButton() {
            if (!scope.tweet && !watchAdded) {
              // wait for data if it hasn't loaded yet
              watchAdded = true;
              var unbindWatch = scope.$watch('tweet', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                  renderTweetButton();

                  // only need to run once
                  unbindWatch();
                }
              });
              return;
            } else {
              element.html('<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="' + scope.tweet + '" data-url="' + (scope.tweetUrl || $location.absUrl()) + '">Tweet</a>');
              $window.twttr.widgets.load(element.parent()[0]);
            }
          }
        }
      };
    }
  ])

  .directive('pinIt', [
    '$window', '$location',
    function($window, $location) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          pinIt: '=',
          pinItImage: '=',
          pinItUrl: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          if (!$window.parsePins) {
            // Load Pinterest SDK if not already loaded
            (function(d) {
              var f = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0],
                p = d.createElement('SCRIPT');
              p.type = 'text/javascript';
              p.async = true;
              p.src = '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js';
              p['data-pin-build'] = 'parsePins';
              p.onload = function() {
                if (!!$window.parsePins) {
                  renderPinItButton();
                } else {
                  setTimeout(p.onload, 100);
                }
              };
              f.parentNode.insertBefore(p, f);
            }($window.document));
          } else {
            renderPinItButton();
          }

          var watchAdded = false;

          function renderPinItButton() {
            if (!scope.pinIt && !watchAdded) {
              // wait for data if it hasn't loaded yet
              watchAdded = true;
              var unbindWatch = scope.$watch('pinIt', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                  renderPinItButton();

                  // only need to run once
                  unbindWatch();
                }
              });
              return;
            } else {
              element.html('<a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' + (scope.pinItUrl || $location.absUrl()) + '&media=' + scope.pinItImage + '&description=' + scope.pinIt + '" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="beside"></a>');
              $window.parsePins(element.parent()[0]);
            }
          }
        }
      };
    }
  ]);

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS directives for social sharing buttons - Facebook Like, Google+, Twitter and Pinterest</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myController" class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div fb-like></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div fb-like="myModel.Url"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div tweet="myModel.Name" tweet-url="myModel.Url"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div google-plus="myModel.Url"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div pin-it="myModel.Name" pin-it-image="myModel.ImageUrl" pin-it-url="myModel.Url"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="credits text-center">
    <p>
      <a href="http://www.jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/08/01/AngularJS-directives-for-social-sharing-buttons-Facebook-Like-GooglePlus-Twitter-and-Pinterest.aspx">AngularJS directives for social sharing buttons</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="http://www.jasonwatmore.com">www.jasonwatmore.com</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="angulike.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```